# selenium not loading whole page for scraping

Tags: python, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver  # pip install selenium
import time
import re
# importing the module
from pytube import YouTube

def dnload(lnk):
    # where to save
    SAVE_PATH = "C:/Python/amazingrussian" #to_do
    # link of the video to be downloaded
    link=lnk
    yt = YouTube(link)  

    try:
        yt.streams.filter(progressive = True, file_extension = "mp4").first().download(output_path = SAVE_PATH,  filename=None)
    except:
        print("Some Error!"+l)
    time.sleep(15)    
    print('Task Completed!')



# make sure you download chrome driver from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads and put it in folder 'driver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome('driver\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/c/AmazingRussian/videos')  # put here your link

# scroll page down
old_position = 0
new_position = None
position_script = """return (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ?
          window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement ||
          document.body.parentNode || document.body);"""
while new_position != old_position:
    old_position = driver.execute_script(position_script)
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.execute_script(
        """var scrollingElement = (document.scrollingElement ||
         document.body);scrollingElement.scrollTop =
         scrollingElement.scrollHeight;""")    
    new_position = driver.execute_script(position_script) 
time.sleep(100)    
source_page = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
driver.close()


pattern = "/watch?(.*?)webPageType"
with open('quotes.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
  for x in re.findall(pattern, source_page):
     lnk = "https://www.youtube.com/watch"+x.replace('"', "")
     f.write(lnk)
     f.write('\n')

for x in re.findall(pattern, source_page):
 lnk = "https://www.youtube.com/watch"+x.replace('"', "")
 dnload(lnk)
```

I am trying to download videos from youtube playlist but it seems the whole webpage is not getting loaded by selenium

Should I add any more code to fix it
The main issue is that the page fully loads but its not reflected. When I load the page in a browser on my own, all is fine.

Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by using `WebDriverWait` to wait until the element/elements you want are loaded.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((Your Element)))
```

This will wait for the element of your choice to be loaded before moving on to getting it. If the page takes long to load, you will have to change the number `5` to a time of your choice. Currently, it will wait for 5 seconds before giving us an error, but that may be too small for others.